# Is python's Queue incomplete or is my design flawed

Tags: python, multithreading

The Queue from python is practical for multithreading, but it does not support stopping the worker threads when the queue is empty indefinitely.

For example, consider this:

```
queue = Queue()

def process(payload):
  time.sleep(random())

def work(item):
  while(True):
    payload = queue.get()
    try:
      process(payload)
    except:
      print("TERROR ERROR!")
    finally:
      queue.task_done()

threads = dict()
for thread_id in range(10):
  threads[thread_id] = Thread(target=work)
  threads[thread_id].deamon = True
  threads[thread_id].start()

for payload in range(100):
  queue.put(payload)

queue.join();
```

So this works great, but not really. The queue.join() waits for all the items to be reported done, and then the main-thread finishes, but the worker threads will wait indefinitely. If this would be the end of the (unix) process, of course, we can leave it to the OS, but if it continues, there are these waiting threads that are spilling resources.

So then we implement a sentinel, EOQ, or bottom or whatever you wish call it:

```
class Sentinel:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

def work(item):
  while(True):
    payload = queue.get()
    if type(payload) == Sentinel:
      queue.task_done()
      break
    # ...

threads = dict()
# ...

for thread_id in threads:
  queue.put(Sentinel())
queue.join();
```

This is a nicer solution, as the threads now stop. Nevertheless, the code of injecting the sentinels is clumsy, and error prone. Consider that I accidentally have put too few in there, or a worker-thread accidentally processed two, such that other worker threads won't get theirs.

Alternatively:

```
class FiniteQueue(Queue):
  def __init__(self, ....)
    super() .__init__(....)
    self.finished = False

  def put(self, item, ...):
    if self.finished:
      raise AlreadyFinished()
    super().put(item, ...)

  def set_finished(self):
    self.finished=True

  def get(self, ...):
    if self.finished:
      raise AlreadyFinished()
    return super().get(....)
```

Obviously, I was lazy and did not make the put() method thread-safe, nevertheless this is very possible to do. This way workers can simply catch the AlreadyFinished object, and stop.

The main queue can simply apply a set_finished() when all the payloads have entered. The queue can then detect when it will not get more payloads, and report this to the workers (or consumers if you wish).

Why doesn't the python queue provide the set_finished() functionality? It does not interfere with the endless_queue use case, but does support a finite pipeline of processing.

Am I missing an obvious error in this design? Is this something one should not want? Is there a simpler alternative to the provided FiniteQueue?

Comment: What you want is generally known as a breakable queue.  It's not unreasonable, but it's just not that common a feature in standard queues.  (Perl, for instance, added breakability over a decade after its standard queue was introduced.)  People use sentinels, busy poll looping, etc. to achieve the same effect.  Also appropriate is designing the program so that the consumers' shutdown is inconsequential.  Indeed, python (since 2.5) makes this easy with the non-standard queue extension `task_done` and `join` — now your producer can be sure that all the workers are finished.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the sentinel problem, I put in the same number as sentinels as there are worker threads. If a worker detects a thread, it quits, so no duplicates are possible. As sentinel I used a reference to a function - which is never called.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  test_queue.py
#  
#  Copyright 2015 John Coppens <john@jcoppens.com>
#  
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#  
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#  
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston,
#  MA 02110-1301, USA.
#  
#

from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import time, random

NR_WORKERS = 10
queue = Queue()

# The sentinel function below is bot necessary - you can use None as sentinel, 
# though this function might be useful if the worker wants to do something
# after the last job (like wash his hands :)  (Thanks Darren Ringer)

# def sentinel():
#    pass

def process(payload):
    time.sleep(random.random())
    print payload

def work():
    while(True):
        payload = queue.get()
        print "Got from queue: ", payload
        #if payload == sentinel:
        if payload == None:         # See comment above
            queue.task_done()
            break
        process(payload)
        queue.task_done()

threads = dict()
for id in range(NR_WORKERS):
    print "Creating worker ", id
    threads[id] = Thread(target=work)
    #threads[id].deamon = False
    threads[id].start()

for payload in range(100):
    queue.put(payload)

for stopper in range(NR_WORKERS):
    # queue.put(sentinel)             # See comment at def sentinel()
    queue.put(None)

queue.join();
```

EDIT: Thanks to @DarrenRinger for the suggestion of using None. I had tried that before but it failed (because of another issue, I suspect)

Comment: Even simpler, I have seen None itself used as a sentinel value in a lot of the code out there.

Comment: @DarrenRinger You know, I tried None at the beginning, but had a problem - probably due to some other issue. Thanks - I'll add that to the reply - with reference, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with *Sentinel* objects is correct and good. It is impossible for `worker` thread `accidentally process two` *Sentinel* objects, because its processing cycle breaks when it found one of them.

`FiniteQueue` approach will not work, because setting `finished` flag will not awake worker, blocked at statement `super().get(....)`.

This is common problem for the most programming languages, which support threads: *blocking wait of two conditions at once*. In your case, `get()` method should wait for:

1) queue become non-empty,

2) or finish flag is set to true

For being correct, wait method must be aware of both conditions. This makes usage of ready-made objects with `wait` support harder. Some languages supports some sort of *thread interruption*, which awakes blocked threads. Python seems lack of such mechanism.

Comment: It is possible for a worker to process, by bug, for example by not breaking the outer loop but some inner loop. You are right about the FiniteQueue, nevertheless, when implemented in the Queue itself, one can do a notify_all (assuming the Queue uses a condition variable instead of a mutex). What is the problem with wake being aware of the finished flag as wel? i.e. while self.empty and not self.finished: self.cv.wait().

Comment: `What is the problem with wake being aware of the finished flag as wel?` - The problem is that there are too many usages of the queue: e.g, one may want another  flag for terminate put() waiting. Taking into account `finished` flag requires complication of the `Queue` interface and implementation: get() should return special value or throw exception in case of `finished` flag. Actually, you can implement your variant of queue, with all features you need. This is not a hard work.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use an [`Event`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects) object shared by all workers instead of a sentinel to avoid mixing data and sentinel accidentally. Also make sure you implement blocking on `queue.get()` and a timeout not to waste resources.

```
from __future__ import print_function 
from threading import Thread, Event, current_thread 
from Queue import Queue import time

queue = Queue() 
evt = Event()

def process(payload):   
    time.sleep(1)

def work():   
    tid = current_thread().name
    # try until signaled not to   
    while(not evt.is_set()):
      try:
        # block for max 1 second
        payload = queue.get(True, 1)
        process(payload)
      except Exception as e:
        print("%s thread exception %s" % (tid, e)) 
      else:
        # calling task_done() in finally may cause too many calls
        # resulting in an exception -- only call it once a task has actually been done
        queue.task_done()

threads = dict() 
for thread_id in range(10):   
    threads[thread_id] = Thread(target=work)                 
    threads[thread_id].deamon = True  
    threads[thread_id].start()
for payload in range(10):
   queue.put(payload)
queue.join() 
# all workers will end in approx 1 second at most
evt.set()
```

Comment: With timeouted `get()` simple flag is sufficient, event is not needed.